# Application crashes with PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

Enabled Hermes request `PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`
Application crashes on device production release.
What's going wrong?

There is a question whether Hermes is supported.
In the developer version I used Hermes enabled and there were no problems.

```
Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.1, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203
    Xcode: 11.1/11A1027 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
Library version: 2.0.2
```

Comment: have you tried to give permissions manually from the settings of the smartphone? Maybe you are not calling for the permissions and just the app explode.

Comment: in developer mode everything is fine, both on the emulator and on the device. I don't see any sense in that

Comment: I try to remember and it sounds in my mind like in debug mode the apps assumes all permissions.

Comment: Try to add coarse location too.

Comment: I added this permission

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: What appears in the log when the app crashes? Try to debug it with Android Studio